# Django redirect/call with parameter from another function

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth

I'm building application with custom python-social-auth pipline for logining via facebook.
The situation is so simple, I need to redirect user from non-view function to url with parameter.

Here is my related urls:

```
url(r'^.*', login, name = 'login'),
url(r'^logout/.*', logout, name = 'FBAuth.views.logout'),
url(r'^/new_user/.*', login, {'new_user':1}, name = 'new_user' ),
url(r'^succeeded/.*', login, {'new_user':2}, name = 'succeeded' ),
```

from views.py:

```
def login(request, new_user=None):
    logger.debug("I'm in login view, new_user = %s", new_user)
    message = 'Welcome to application!'
    if new_user:
        if new_user == 1: #new one
            message = 'Wellcome to our app! Thanks for registration'
        else: 
            if new_user == 2: #loggined
                message = "Successfully logged in"
            else:
                message = new_user
    context = RequestContext(request, {
         'request': request, 'user': request.user, 'message' : message})
    return render_to_response('login.html', context_instance=context)
```

custom.py:

```
def check_if_exists(strategy,  request, *args, **kwargs):
    login_type = strategy.request.GET.get('login_type')

    if kwargs['is_new']:
        ...
        some code
        ...
    else:
        #if login_type == 2: 
            #raise AuthAlreadyAssociated          #need to add message
            new_user = 1
            #return redirect('/new_user/')
            #return redirect('/new_user/', {'new_user' : new_user} )
            return login(new_user=1)
            #return redirect(reverse('new_user'))
            #reverse('FBAuth.views.login', kwargs={'new_user' : new_user} ) #, new_user=new_user) #, args =(new_user,))
            #reverse(redirect_uri, args=(backend,))
    return None
```

Here is my auth pipeline:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'FBAuth.facebook.check_if_exists',     
    'social.pipeline.user.get_username',
    'social.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social.pipeline.user.user_details',
)
```

The pipelene cals by url:

```
 href="{% url 'social:begin' 'facebook' %}?next={{ request.path }}&login_type={{1}}"
```

I tried a million variants, nothing works. Redirection always fails or I get new_user=None in my view.

Please, help me to find some way to pass my parameter.

**Note:** I also tried:

```
return redirect('/new_user/1/')
```

and

```
return redirect('/new_user/?new_user=1/')
```

for the url:

```
url(r'^/new_user/(?P<new_user>)/$', login, name = 'new_user' ),
```

The page is opened, but no message (new_user in None)

Comment: What is calling that `check_if_exists` function?

Comment: That's a part of the auth pipeline from python-social-auth, it calls from next  function, I'll add it to description.

Comment: With the current code (i.e. with `return login(new_user=1)`), what happens? And what should happen instead exactly?

Comment: This variant doesnt work ar all.
This one works `return redirect(reverse('new_user'))` but my view doesn't get any parameters, `new_user` is `None`

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is in the way you are handling urls.

```
url(r'^/new_user/(?P<new_user>)/$', login, name = 'new_user' )
```

While redirecting use this.

```
return redirect('/new_user/1/')
```

This is not tested. Hope this helps.

Comment: Do I need  to parse this in my view in some another way?

Comment: No change in view required. Your view should have  _new_user_ variable set to 1. I think that is what you wanted, as per your code.

Comment: But my `new_user` is still `None`

Comment: Can you paste the url and check_if_exists code here please.